# Validate a google Authentication Code in Net Core API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, .net-core, google-signin

I want to validate a google Authentication Code in my Net Core API with a [Google's API](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=google.apis&prerelease=true&sortOrder=relevance) or **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google**. I've seen people usually make a http call to validate the [one-time Code](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow) following [this guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#exchange-authorization-code) but I think to make the application more robust the validation should be executed with the a proper Google API however I can't find an example code doing it except processing all OAuth flow that's not my case because I already have **one-time Code** (Authentication Code) gotten by my android application. Is it possible for these Google APIs to validate just the **one-time Code**? If I can which API should I use and how do I do it?

Btw my android application will be using the back end service a lot so I'm thinking on creating another token for the user not to be prompted with google login every time he uses the service but shouldn't be easier to use the same google's Access Token? I think that they advice to use one-time Code to avoid been caught with man in the middle attack in the future, but if I'm already giving another token for the user access my service shouldn't I use the google's instead already?